Accessing the files in a folder of google drive using google oauth
I am trying to create a web application using FastAPI for backend and ReactJS for frontend. I need the users to give me a link of a folder in their google drive in the frontend. I then need to access the files in that folder from my backend.
I created a new project in console.cloud.google.com and created client id and secret for oauth2.0 with drive apis consent. I set up oauth authentication in fastapi. Now, I need to create an endpoint from where I can access the files inside the folder whose link is given by the user.

from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
import uvicorn, requests
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.auth.transport import requests as google_requests
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google import auth

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost:5173",
]

app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="maihoonjiyan")


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

SCOPES = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/docs",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
]


@app.get("/auth")
def authentication(request: Request, token: str):
    try:
        user = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(
            token,
            google_requests.Request(),
            "client_id",
        )
        content = {"message": "Logged In Successfully"}
        response = JSONResponse(content=content)
        response.set_cookie(
            key="email",
            value=user["email"],
            max_age=600,
            httponly=True,
            samesite="lax",
            secure=True,
        )
        response.set_cookie(
            key="name",
            value=user["name"],
            max_age=600,
            httponly=True,
            samesite="lax",
            secure=True,
        )
        response.set_cookie(
            key="access_token",
            value=token,
            max_age=600,
            httponly=True,
            samesite="lax",
            secure=True,
        )
        return response
    except ValueError:
        return "unauthorized"


@app.get("/drive")
def drive():
    return "SUCCESS"


@app.get("/")
def check(request: Request):
    return "hi"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="localhost", port=8000, reload=True)

This is my setup. /drive is the endpoint I am trying to create. I have tried things like sending a request directly to the drive API, building a service, but these methods give me a 401 unauthorized response. I found plenty of solutions online to access my own google drive but not on accessing other's google drive. Is this possible?
